# Pointing an array in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, static

I want to point an array in c++ , is it possible ?

My main code :

```
#include "ArrayPointerClass.h"

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    float arr[2];

    ArrayPointerClass::pointingArray(&arr);

    return 0;
}
```

ArrayPointerClass.h

```
#pragma once
static class ArrayPointerClass
{
public:
    ArrayPointerClass();
    ~ArrayPointerClass();
    static void pointingArray(float* arr[2]);
};
```

ArrayPointerClass.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "ArrayPointerClass.h"


ArrayPointerClass::ArrayPointerClass()
{
}


ArrayPointerClass::~ArrayPointerClass()
{
}

void ArrayPointerClass::pointingArray(float* arr[2]){

    float newArray[2] = { 2.2f, 2.2f };
    *arr = newArray;

}
```

I've got this error :
Error   3   error C2653: 'ArrayPointerClass' : is not a class or namespace name c:\users\alex\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\pointerarray\pointerarray\pointerarray.cpp  13  1   PointerArray

Error   3   error C3861: 'pointingArray': identifier not found  c:\users\alex\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\pointerarray\pointerarray\pointerarray.cpp  13  1   PointerArray

I know in C++ arrays ,arrays without length defined are not allowed . is it the reason ?

Thanks for your support

Comment: You can't assign to C arrays, if that's your intent. `std::array` works a lot better, and the pointer and reference syntax is like normal.

Comment: Use `std::vector`. That's what it's for.

Comment: One problem with this code that's not (currently) addressed in any of the answers is the source of your first error:  You're including `ArrayPointerClass.h` before `stdafx.h`, the precompiled header (PCH) for VC++.  When it parses the PCH it will skip everything up to the inclusion of `stdafx.h`, causing your `ArrayPointerClass.h` header to be skipped and not included, which generates your errors reported in your question.

Answer (score 1):

*arr = newArray; will not work you can't copy a C array like that .
You could have done memcpy() or std::copy() like;

```
memcpy( newArray, arr, 2);

std::copy( newArray, newArray+2, arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to create a static class in c++. **static** keyword can be applied to objects and functions.
And each array name is a pointer. Therefore subscripts cannot be given in the parameter. It is sufficient to provide the pointer type.

The modified code which works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


class ArrayPointerClass
{
 public:
 ArrayPointerClass();
 ~ArrayPointerClass();
 static void pointingArray(float* arr);
};

ArrayPointerClass::ArrayPointerClass()
{
}

ArrayPointerClass::~ArrayPointerClass()
{
}

 void ArrayPointerClass::pointingArray(float* arr){

 float newArray[2] = { 2.2f, 2.2f };
 arr = newArray;

}


int main()
{
  float arr[2];

  ArrayPointerClass obj;
  obj.pointingArray(arr);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: In your example "newArray[2]" is created in the stack. It will be destroyed in the end of pointingArray function. And because of that "arr" will be assigned with dangling pointer.

Answer (score -2):

Thanks everybody for your answers (even there were partially working)
I found my self a solution

```
// PointerArray.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;



int* test() {

    int size_needed = 2;

    int* a = new int[size_needed];
    a[0] = 0;
    a[1] = 0;

    return a;
}


int main()
{
    //int arr[2] = { 1, 1 };
    int* arr = test();


    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        cout << arr[i] << std::endl;
    }
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are allocating "a" but you are not deallocating it by delete. This will cause you trouble in a big scale project.

Comment: CANT ASK ANYMORE QUESTIONS.... PROGRAMMING IS MY LIFE AND I CANT ASK NO MORE HELP , WHY ???????????????

Comment: If you're using this site as a help site, you're using it wrong. This is not a help site but a question and answer repository, and that's a big difference.

Comment: No problem, but I dont understand that judgment.Anyway , I dont have time to loose to explain about my poor unfair feelings , I will create another account ( PS : I hate these downvoters who think they are superior than me, and causing this ban. I answered on questions on Stackoverflow with my decent knowledge and i get people like you judging me and downvoting my posts without any deep reasons )